# Issues with Sokuon Conversion in pykakasi Library for Japanese to Romaji Translation in Python

Tags: python, nlp, cjk

I am attempting to use the pykakasi library in Python to convert Japanese text to Romaji. However, I am encountering issues with the conversion of sokuon (促音). Here is the code I am using:

```py
import pykakasi

def japanese_to_romaji(text):
    kks = pykakasi.kakasi()
    result = kks.convert(text)
    return ''.join([entry['hepburn'] for entry in result])

example_text = "振って もっと振って 内圧高めて放出寸前"
print(japanese_to_romaji(example_text))
```

The output is as follows:

```
futsute mottofutsute naiatsutakametehoushutsusunzen
```

As you can see, for the word `もっと`, pykakasi correctly translates it to `motto`. However, for the word `振って`, pykakasi translates it to `futsute`.

I am uncertain if this is a bug in pykakasi or an issue with my code.

Should I be configuring pykakasi differently?

Or should I consider using a different library for Japanese morphological analysis for Romaji conversion?

How do Japanese developers typically handle such issues?